# Please How do I sort range of time in ascending order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, time

I have an array of objects that has "time" and "vote"
 I wish to sort the time in an ascending order. Please how do I go about this?

```
[ { time: '10:00 - 11:00', vote: 0 },
  { time: '7:00 - 8:00', vote: 2 },
  { time: '12:00 - 1:00', vote: 0 },
  { time: '11:00 - 12:00', vote: 2 },
  { time: '4:00 - 5:00', vote: 0 },
  { time: '2:00 - 3:00', vote: 0 },
  { time: '5:00 - 6:00', vote: 0 },
  { time: '9:00 - 10:00', vote: 2 },
  { time: '8:00 - 9:00', vote: 1 },
  { time: '1:00 - 2:00', vote: 1 },
  { time: '3:00 - 4:00', vote: 0 } ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `string#localeCompare` to sort your time.

```js
let data = [ { time: '10:00 - 11:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '7:00 - 8:00', vote: 2 }, { time: '12:00 - 1:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '11:00 - 12:00', vote: 2 }, { time: '4:00 - 5:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '2:00 - 3:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '5:00 - 6:00', vote: 0 }, { time:'9:00 - 10:00', vote: 2 }, { time: '8:00 - 9:00', vote: 1 }, { time: '1:00 - 2:00', vote: 1 }, { time: '3:00 - 4:00', vote: 0 } ];
data.sort((a,b) => a.time.localeCompare(b.time, undefined, {numeric:true}));
console.log(data);
```

```js
let data = [ { time: '10:00 - 11:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '7:00 - 8:00', vote: 2 }, { time: '12:00 - 1:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '11:00 - 12:00', vote: 2 }, { time: '4:00 - 5:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '2:00 - 3:00', vote: 0 }, { time: '5:00 - 6:00', vote: 0 }, { time:'9:00 - 10:00', vote: 2 }, { time: '8:00 - 9:00', vote: 1 }, { time: '1:00 - 2:00', vote: 1 }, { time: '3:00 - 4:00', vote: 0 } ],
    result = data.map(({time},i) => [new Date('1970/01/01 ' + time.split(" - ")[0]), i])
                 .sort((a,b) => a[0] - b[0])
                 .map(([,index]) => data[index]);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Thank You. I had something similar to that. 
  It means i may just have to change the time format to "12:00 - 13:00" and so on. 
to get me required result.